# Maximum Achievable distance, given the maximum delay, in optical fiber (single mode) and ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, transmission, optical, fiber

I have the following problem to solve. I have to find the maximum achievable distance between two nodes of a network, given the maximum delay possible between them. The connection can be single mode optical fiber or shared ethernet connection.

Thanks to the help of some users, I was able to calculate the distance of the link using the propagation speed inside fiber and ethernet. However, the length that comes out is unrealistic. so there must be other parameters I have to take into account, to get this distance.

For example, one of the max delays I can have is 8,5 ms. in optical fiber, that is more than 1000 kms, which is absurd. I was thinking that maybe attenuation has to be considered, so additional delay maybe from repeaters?

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Delay is rarely the limiting factor for distance, except for some very high-bandwidth protocols intended for strictly local use. Signal strength (signal to noise ratio) is generally what comes into play first.

Comment: *8,5 ms. in optical fiber, that is more than 1000 kms, which is absurd* um, no, that sounds reasonable. Speed of light in fibre is about 2·10⁸ m/s.

Comment: I mean, it is absurd considering the realistic scenario of this project.

Comment: Other than a latency constraint, how would I be able to define a maximum distance, also by means of SNR? even with the use of amplifiers/repeaters

Comment: Fiber can be used to talk to the other side of the planet, so aside from the time of flight delay, you are unconstrained. A fiber optic system used at 1000s of kilometers will be very different (more expensive) then one used within a building though since it will overcome attenuation.